# Using jquery.Jcrop.js in custom extension

Tags: development

I want to implement jquery.Jcrop.js in a custom extension.

Because this look great! [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)

And it's bundled with Joomla, located under:
media\system\js\jquery.Jcrop.js

And it's used in:
administrator\components\com_templates\views\template\tmpl\default.php
administrator\templates\hathor\html\com_templates\template

But it looks like it's not working when used in a template. See image.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to implement / or where it is used in a Joomla extension?

Regards,

Gosling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error I believe is due to the following console log error:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id
>
> > trueSize:   469,159]

It currently a bug in Joomla. I'll have a quick look through the code to see if there's a fix, but it might be an idea to report this bug to the Joomla-CMS repository on Github.

#### Update:

I've fixed it. See the [Pull Request](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/6214)

Comment: Update: I merged it :P

Comment: Don't know why I didn't check the console myself! :-)